# Output delimited file from SAS data set without explicit PUT

Tags: sas

I am used to R where writing out a data.frame is as easy as write.csv(), but in SAS you have to specify every column you want written out when you want to output a data set.

How can you write out a delimited file with every column in a SAS data set, including the header?

A good set to use would be dataset SASHELP.BUY for an example.

Comment: Why don't you try PROC EXPORT.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a macro for this that I have treasured through the years. Probably could abstract it a little more to accept an extension and delimiter type... but you get the idea.

Script:

```
%MACRO DLM_DUMP(DSNAME, SASLB);

  PROC SQL;
  SELECT CATS(NAME) INTO :NAME 
  SEPARATED BY ',' 
  FROM DICTIONARY.COLUMNS 
  WHERE LIBNAME="&SASLB" AND MEMNAME="&DSNAME";
  QUIT;

  DATA _NULL_;
    SET &SASLB..&DSNAME;
    FILE "&DSNAME..csv" DSD DLM=",";
    IF _N_ = 1 THEN PUT "&NAME";
    PUT (_all_) (&);
  RUN;

%MEND;

%DLM_DUMP(BUY,SASHELP);
```

Result:

```
$ head -4 BUY.csv 
DATE,AMOUNT
01JAN1996,-110000
01JAN1997,-1000
01JAN1998,-1000
```

Answer (score 1):

As `data _null_` notes, `PROC EXPORT` is the trivial solution to this, very equivalent to `write.csv` (just like `PROC IMPORT` is very equivalent to `read.csv`).

```
proc export data=sashelp.class outfile="c:\temp\test.csv" dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

Of course that could generate CSV, Tab delimited, Excel, etc., by changing the `dbms`.